# Direct LDAP User Authentication for API Access without Separate Bind User

Tags: authentication, ldap, jndi

There is a API which can be accessed with userName='emmma' with password='secretxxxx' (these are not real users , they are other programs accessing it) and the password has to be changed  every 6 months , currently userName and password is stored in the db. But we not want to maintain this user, instead rely on ldap to authenticate user.

I have 2 approaches in mind
**Approach 1**: create new user say 'admin' in ldap  for binding , after successful binding authenticate the user 'emma'.
Concern:This requires us to maintain the newly added user 'admin' 's userName password on application side , ( new entry in db and frequent password change)
**Approach 2**:  Successful bind to ldap implies that user creds are valid .Instead of using different user to bind , bind using the user 'emma'.

It would be helpful if you could let me know , if its okay to go with the Approach 2 also please suggest if you have any other alternate approach in mind.

I'm using Spring boot in the backend :

```
LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
//code to set url , bind user dn , password
.
.
.
//
contextSource.getContext(userDn,password); -> if this thorws no exception , i'm concluding that user is valid
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with (2) as long as you store the full DN of the user entry, not just the username. The reason for the usual 2-phase approach is that normally users don't know their own DNs, only their username, so there has to be a search, and you don't want your DIT world-searchable, so you use a well-known admin user for the search.

Comment: Not necessarily a well-known _admin_ user! Just a user that has 'read' access to the whole OU. (For example, in AD, making the service user a member of the "Pre-Win2000 Access" group might suffice.)

Comment: Don't you rotate your database password every 6 month? Doing this rigth with [dynamic database passwords](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/db-credentials/database-secrets) and [dynamic ldap passwords](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/secrets/ldap#dynamic-credentials) is a large project... The only quick and quite dirty way, looking only at this very specific use-case, is to have all your users in the same tree and insert the username in a string to create the DN (ex: UID=%s,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com)

Comment: @ixe013 I don't believe in expiring passwords myself. No reason to change a password that hasn't been leaked.

Comment: If you can **reliably** tell if a given password has been leaked, you are a millionaire.  If you ask me, a brand new ephemeral password should be given out each time one is required (application starts, connection lost, etc.). It expires in 60 seconds or so., enough to use it about once.

Comment: @ixe013 Not implementable with LDAP. Not sure it even makes sense. How do you authenticate the entity you’re giving the password to?

Comment: It's about trust. You build a chain of trust that starts *somewhere*. For example, you have processes in place to secure your Cloud presence ownership. You trust your infrastructure from that root of trust. You can assemble more tooling and process so that when you deploy your application, it gets instance credentials **from the platform you trust**. Those instance credentials can be used to access Vault or your cloud platform's Secrets Manager (better, a cloud service itself). Without that root of trust, you are just moving the password problem around. You get to pick the file, that's it.